# Add plugin to Datastax Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to add the [Carrot Clustering plugin](https://github.com/carrot2/solr-integration-strategies) to Solr(v. 4.10.3) in Datastax(v. 4.7.3-1).
When I'm following [these](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchConfLibPath.html) instructions and put the JAR's in /usr/share/dse/solr/lib directory, I do see the libraries in java.​class.​path but it doesn't show up in plugins/other.
When I'm using the library (although I can't see it) I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR [http-10.10.10.10-8983-2] 2016-05-17 06:19:49,955  SolrException.java:150 - org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening clustering/carrot2/default-attributes.xml
            at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:920)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraCoreContainer.doReload(CassandraCoreContainer.java:904)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraCoreContainer.create(CassandraCoreContainer.java:324)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.SolrCoreResourceManager.reloadCore(SolrCoreResourceManager.java:434)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.admin.CassandraCoreAdminHandler.handleReloadAction(CassandraCoreAdminHandler.java:188)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:225)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:188)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:163)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:736)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:258)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.servlet.CassandraDispatchFilter.doFilter(CassandraDispatchFilter.java:108)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.audit.SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.doFilter(SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.java:213)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.audit.SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.doFilter(SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.java:213)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.CassandraAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(CassandraAuthorizationFilter.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.RepeatablePOSTQueryFilter.doFilter(RepeatablePOSTQueryFilter.java:63)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.DseAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DseAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error opening clustering/carrot2/default-attributes.xml
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraResourceLoader.getResource(CassandraResourceLoader.java:42)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraResourceLoader.openResource(CassandraResourceLoader.java:57)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.clustering.carrot2.SolrResourceLocator.getAll(SolrResourceLocator.java:66)
            at org.carrot2.util.resource.ResourceLookup.getAll(ResourceLookup.java:114)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.clustering.carrot2.CarrotClusteringEngine.init(CarrotClusteringEngine.java:145)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.clustering.ClusteringComponent.inform(ClusteringComponent.java:117)
            at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:655)
            at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:903)
            ... 35 more
    Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No resource clustering/carrot2/default-attributes.xml for core solr_core.table, did you miss to upload it?
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.SolrCoreResourceManager.getResource(SolrCoreResourceManager.java:811)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.SolrCoreResourceManager.readResource(SolrCoreResourceManager.java:183)
            at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraResourceLoader.getResource(CassandraResourceLoader.java:38)
            ... 42 more
```

What do I miss?

Comment: The error is saying that you haven't uploaded the resource clustering/carrot2/default-attributes.xml. Have you uploaded that resource?

Comment: No, I don't know what is this file. I did upload the carrot JAR and the clustering JAR and all of their dependencies' JAR's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carrot is telling you it needs to read that resource. You need to upload it to DSE Search so it can be picked up. Upload adjusting this to your convenience:

`curl -s --data-binary @<xmlFileHere> -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8' http://<hostHere>:8983/solr/resource/<coreNameHere>/clustering/carrot2/default-attributes.xml`

Make sure you upload to DSE Search all resources that are needed. DSE Search does not read them from the file system, you have to upload them instead.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea why I had to do it? Doesn't carrot has default configurations? Is it related to the fact I'm using Datastax?

Comment: You had to do it because carrot is looking for a *resource* in std Solr is on the filesystem on installation. Resources on DSE Search have to be *uploaded* instead.